# Facebook API - Page country restriction Set to specific country getting error - Unsupported get request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

My Facebook Page country restriction Set to specific country. 
so , when I am using application access token with following API to download json for above pageid -

https://graph.facebook.com/PageId?access_token=xxxxx&method=GET&metadata=true&format=json

getting following error  : -

{"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}.

Please any one have any idea how we can solve this issue ?